# Got a code snippet for getting Location, don't wanna take Network Location into consideration

Tags: android, gps

I am pretty new to Android, and I took a code snippet from stackoverflow with getting Location. It works perfect, but when network internet is activated, it takes the coordinates from there, and they aren't quite accurate, or at all(sometimes getting 5km+ errors).

I want my location code getting snippet to get only GPS location, but my current knowledge does not allow me to modify it such that i can obtain that.

Here is the code snippet:

```
package com.fourbox.bocterapp;

/**
 * Created by Soulstorm on 10/14/2014.
 */
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyLocation {
    Timer timer1;
    LocationManager lm;
    LocationResult locationResult;
    boolean gps_enabled=false;
    boolean network_enabled=false;

    public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result)
    {
        //I use LocationResult callback class to pass location value from MyLocation to user code.
        locationResult=result;
        if(lm==null)
            lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
        try{gps_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}
        try{network_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}

        //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
        if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
            return false;

        if(gps_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
        if(network_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,     locationListenerNetwork);
        timer1=new Timer();
        timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 50000);
        return true;
    }

    LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
            Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null;
            if(gps_enabled)
                gps_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if(network_enabled)
                net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            //if there are both values use the latest one
            if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
                if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
                    locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                else
                    locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                return;
            }

            if(gps_loc!=null){
                locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                return;
            }
            if(net_loc!=null){
                locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                return;
            }
            locationResult.gotLocation(null);
        }
    }

    public static abstract class LocationResult{
        public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);

    }
}
```

Here is how i use it:

```
MyLocation.LocationResult locationResult = new MyLocation.LocationResult() {
                        @Override
                        public void gotLocation(Location location) {
                            currentUserLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                            currentUserLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                            new RemoteDataTask().execute();
                        }
                    };
                    MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
                    myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult);
```

Can you please help me to modify my code so my snippet does not get the Network coordinates, only the GPS ones?

Thanks in advance!
Respects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two lines in the GetLastLocation class is where you subscribe to location updates via the network location provider.

Simply remove these two lines of code to no longer receive updates from the the network location provider.

```
if(network_enabled)
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,     locationListenerNetwork);
```

Note, location updates from the GPS can take longer than from the network. So if speed is an issue, an alternative approach would be to still use the network location updates, but filter on the accuracy value. This would look something like this:

```
LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if (location.getAccuracy() > THRESHOLD) {
            return;
        }

        timer1.cancel();
        locationResult.gotLocation(location);
        lm.removeUpdates(this);
        lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
};
```

Comment: In your code you have two location callbacks. One for gps location updates, called locationListenerGps and one for network location updates called locationListenerNetwork. If you remove the above two lines, does the locationListenerNetwork onLocationChanged(Location location) method still get called?

Comment: I tried it again, but the Coordinates obtaining process got significantly slower, and if it doesn't get the location in the given timer, it crashes. Sometimes it works, sometimes is crashes.

Comment: Locations from the GPS will be slower than from the network. An alternative approach could be to still use the network provider, and when location updates come through, check the accuracy value and reject it if it is greater than a give threshold

Comment: Then let me ask a question. WiFi internet is considered as a network provider? Does it provide coordinates? Because when i have the WiFi activated(not the network provider), I have pinpoint accuracy, and it gets me the coordinates in 3 seconds.

Comment: The network provider includes the Wifi provider AND the Network cell provider. Results for both are sent via the same listener. So if you have wifi enabled and in range of hotspots you will have greater accuracy (and it will often be quicker than GPS)

Comment: @VladIancu did that answer your question :)